# Javascript Validation On Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Hello I have got a newsletter form. Not too sure what's wrong with the validation but when a user clicks the subscribe button without entering any values into the fields it submits anyway and takes you to the external url. Is there a way of making it so that both fields have to be filled in order for the subscribe button to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the clause `required="true"` into the inputs that must be filled in the html, like this:

```
print '<tr><td>' . $myNameLabel . '</td><td><input required = "true" class="modns inputbox ' . $mod_class_suffix . '"  type="text" name="m_name'.$unique_id.'" size="' . $nameWidth . '"';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. So easy and can't believe I left it out. Thanks very much.

Comment: The required attribute is new  in HTML5 it will work in latest browsers only it is recommended to  validate